# jQuery get, receive an int value from the php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am making a load more paginate button, I'm stuck at two things that are both similar.  I don't have a way of increasing pages, and I don't have a way for the script to know when the paginate is finished.  Here is my jQuery code for the load more:

```
$(document).on('click', '#loadmore', function() {
     $.get('/artistprofileloadmore.php?page=2&aid=$aid', function(data) {
    $("#append").append(data);
    });
});
```

I can easily solve this if there is a way for the jQuery to receive a variable value from the php file. So is there?  Simply put, if the paginate is finished, the variable $end=1 is set, otherwise it is set to 0, is there a way I can use the jQuery to check when the variable $end==1 and then I would remove the div #loadmore to remove the next page button.

For the next page, is there a way that I can set jQuery to increase a variable every time it is run, which will increase the page number? The variable would be used instead of this two:

```
?page=2
```

and increase every click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PHP return a JSON like this
`{"artists"="The Artists profiles","isLast"=true}`

```
var pageNum = 1;
$(document).on('click', '#loadmore', function () {
    $.get('/artistprofileloadmore.php?page=' + pageNum + '&aid=$aid', function (data) {
        $("#append").append(data.artists);
        if(data.isLast){
          $('#loadmore').hide();
        }else{
           pageNum++;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: welcome! I've removed qoutes from the boolean value, I believe "false" would be interpreted as a string

Answer (score 1):

I think on the PHP page you want to divide the content logically into the html code to be loaded into your container and also a variable containing whatever it is you want the php to send along with this page content.  You can have, ex,

```
$html = [whatever];
$otherData = [other stuff I need to send along with html];
$return['html'] = $html;
$return['otherData'] = $otherData;
echo json_encode($return);
```

You then have to tweak the javascript to be able to receive this data.  I suggest reading up on the JQuery AJAX API.

(I'm fond of JSON, but it's just one option for formatting the data the server sends.)